# What are the key responsibilities of a Hindu?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras

According to scripture, what are the key responsibilities of a Hindu?

Comment: What is your Varna? What is your Sampradaya?

Comment: It would be better to clarify bit about type of responsibility

Comment: Responsibilities of a man or a woman? Responsibilities towards family or society? Right now the question looks very broad.

Comment: https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/7/11/8-12 might be helpful..